# tikz gd drawing library not drawing arrows in edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm using Graph Drawing with Force algorithm to place nodes and edges, but for some reason the edges do not display the arrows when [spring layout] is used.

It works correctly when manually placing the nodes and the edges without the algorithmic layout.

My question is how to make the **spring layout** display the edge arrows correctly as in the second tikz picture.

Follows the MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,  graphdrawing, quotes }
\usegdlibrary {force}

\tikzset{
    node distance = 20mm,
    provides/.style = {->},
    every edge quotes/.style = {fill=white,sloped},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spring layout]
\node [draw] (a) {A};
\node [draw] (b) {B};
\draw [provides] (a) edge ["stuff"] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (a) {A};
\node [draw, below = of a] (b) {B};
\draw [provides] (a) edge ["stuff"] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, looks like the `graphdrawing` library only catches the options that are given directly at the `edge`, i.e. `\path (a) edge [provides, "stuff"] (b);`. (Don't use `\draw` with only `edge`s.) `graphdrawing` only defines `--` types of edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph Drawing library doesn't seem to make the five different types of edges (`--`, `->`, `<-`, `<->`, `-!-`) available to the user. Every edge will be a `--` edge. (This doesn't yet have anything to do about arrow tips, this is about the direction of the edge where a GD library might interpret these differently.)

Only the options to the `edge` operation will be forwarded to the Graph Drawing algorithm as well when the edge is actually drawn (where `->` means the arrow tip specification).

So you will need to do

```
\path (a) edge [provides, "stuff"] (b);
```

even `every edge` won't get considered.

---

Here's a *hack* that overloads a few styles which set both the arrow tip as well as the edge type. This hack doesn't apply to `edge from parent` (used with the `child` operation) and most likely break other things.

It would be better to use the appropriate hook that is also used by `spring layout` for example.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, graphdrawing, quotes}
\usegdlibrary  {force}
\tikzset{
  node distance = 20mm,
  provides/.style = {->},
  every edge quotes/.style = {fill=white, sloped}}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  edge macro def/.code 2 args={%
    \def\tikz@gd@plain@edge@macro##1##2{%
      \pgfgdedge{\tikz@pp@name{\tikztostart}}{\tikz@pp@name{\tikztotarget}}{#1}{/tikz,#2,##1}{##2}}},
  --/.style ={arrows=-,   edge macro def= {--}{#1}},
  ->/.style ={arrows=->,  edge macro def= {->}{#1}},
  <-/.style ={arrows=<-,  edge macro def= {<-}{#1}},
  <->/.style={arrows=<->, edge macro def={<->}{#1}},
  -!-/.style={arrows=-,   edge macro def={-!-}{#1}, path only}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spring layout]
\node [draw] (a) {A};
\node [draw] (b) {B};
\path[provides] (a) edge ["stuff"] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (a) {A};
\node [draw, below = of a] (b) {B};
\path [provides] (a) edge ["stuff"] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```